# My iPhone's iOS is too old to run Xcode apps

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I own an iPhone 5s. It is running iOS 12. I can't upgrade it to iOS 13. The problem is that I can't install and test my apps I made in Xcode, because new Xcode requires iOS 13. Is there anyway I can make Xcode be able to install apps on devices running older versions of iOS.

Comment: Select the Project, Settings, Info and change `iOS Deployment Target` to `12.0`

Answer (score 3):

Select the Project, Settings, Info and change iOS Deployment Target to the lowest version you want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! In your project configuration, click on your app in the Targets menu.
[image: Where to go]
Then, under "Deployment Info", you can change the target iOS version for your app.
[image: Change target iOS]